# Multiples values in a row

Tags: postgresql

I have to create an api with a database that I will implement later using node.js
I have this one problem though :
I want my foreign key to hold multiple id's because a product can have multiple region. Is there any way I can do it ? I am using postgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE product(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
productName VARCHAR(128),
productCode VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE region(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
regionName VARCHAR(128)
);

ALTER TABLE product ADD COLUMN idRegion INT;
ALTER TABLE product ADD CONSTRAINT idRegion FOREIGN KEY (idRegion) REFERENCES region(id);
```

```
INSERT INTO region (id, regionname) VALUES
(1, 'US'),
(2, 'EUR'),
(3, 'AEJ'),
(4, 'JPY'),
(5, 'EM'),
(6, 'CAD'),
(7, 'Brazil and LatAM');

INSERT INTO product (productName, productcode, idRegion) VALUES
('Index Option', 'IO', (1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
```

Comment: You want to have a third table, product_region for instance, to link product_id and region_id, thus implementing many-to-many relation.

Comment: N:N relationships are best approached with an intermediate table to link the involved entities, as well put by @BjarniRagnarsson

Answer (score 0):

I created a third table thank you guys for your answers

```
CREATE TABLE productRegion(
idRegion INT,
idProduct INT
);

ALTER TABLE productRegion ADD CONSTRAINT idRegion FOREIGN KEY (idRegion) REFERENCES region(id);
ALTER TABLE productRegion ADD CONSTRAINT idProduct FOREIGN KEY (idProduct) REFERENCES product(id);
ALTER TABLE productRegion ADD PRIMARY KEY (idRegion, idProduct);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).